# Is the use of findByUsername allowed on a subclass of User domain in GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a user domain class

```
class User {
String username
String password
}

class Patient extends User {
String something
}
```

in a controller I'm doing a

```
def patient = Patient.findByUsername("me")
```

for which I get a null object on patient.

What is the right way to find a patient via username?

Comment: `User.findByUsername("me")` returns a `User`?

Comment: Yes... It does return a User

Comment: Have you tried a criteria or where query instead? `Patient.withCriteria { eq('username', 'me') }` or `Patient.where { username == 'me' }.list()`

Answer (score 0):

Patient.findBy.... returns a Patient objects
User.findBy returns a User objects + Patient objects.
Inheritance in grails are mapped in the same table . Gorm uses a specific column named 'class' when you use inheritance in domain classes.By this way you can use dynamic finders with inheritance and retrieve the subclass domain that you need.
So you can use dynamic finders to find any object with any column except id column. If you search any object by id you must use User.get(id) or User.load(id).

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Grails you are using? There should not be any reason for getting a record with a User domain query, but not with a Patient domain query.